# Data file - restructure file data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am converting the data file content to new format and writing to the new file.

data file : `f1.txt`

```
user A start 10:30
user B start 10:30
user B end   10:40
user C start 10:50
user A end   11:30
user C end   12:30
```

New Data File: `f2.txt`

```
user A  start  10:30 and end 11:30
user B  start  10:30 and end 10:40
user C  start  10:50 and end 12:30
```

please explain how can write to new data format .

Comment: What is your question exactly? Writing the logic for you doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would group your lines by user category `A`, `B` or `C` in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that looks like something like the following:

```
{'user A': {'start': '10:30', 'end': '11:30'}, 'user B': {'start': '10:30', 'end': '10:40'}, 'user C': {'start': '10:50', 'end': '12:30'}}
```

Then iterate this dictionary and combine the items into lines to write to your file.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# open file for reading, and output file for writing to
with open("f1.txt") as f, open("f2.txt", mode="w") as out:
    d = defaultdict(dict)

    # Group lines
    for line in f:

        # Unpack all columns
        col1, col2, col3, col4 = line.split()

        # Assign start and end times to dict
        d[f"{col1} {col2}"][col3] = col4

    # Iterate dictionary keys and values
    for user, data in d.items():

        # Construct new line to write to file + newline
        line = f"{user}  start  {data['start']} and end {data['end']}\n"

        # Write line to file
        out.write(line)
```

**f2.txt**

```
user A  start  10:30 and end 11:30
user B  start  10:30 and end 10:40
user C  start  10:50 and end 12:30
```

---

**Update (from OP in comments)**

If the data file contains multiple records, then we need to change our approach. One way is to collect the start and end times in lists, then take the `min` and `max`, using [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) as `key` to convert the date strings of format `'%H:%M'` to datetime objects to be compared.

The new `defaultdict` we are after would look something like this:

```
{'user A': {'start': ['10:30', '10:30'], 'end': ['11:30', '11:30']}, 'user B': {'start': ['10:30', '10:30'], 'end': ['10:40', '10:40']}, 'user C': {'start': ['10:50', '10:50'], 'end': ['12:30', '12:30']}}
```

**Example input file:**

```
user A start 10:30
user B start 10:30
user B end 10:40
user C start 10:50
user A end 11:30
user C end 12:30
user A start 10:30
user B start 10:30
user B end 10:40
user C start 10:50
user A end 11:30
user C end 12:30
```

Here is how we might do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

def date_compare_key(date):
    return datetime.strptime(date, '%H:%M')

with open("f1.txt") as f, open("f2.txt", mode="w") as out:
    d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))

    for line in f:
        col1, col2, col3, col4 = line.split()
        d[f"{col1} {col2}"][col3].append(col4)

    for user, data in d.items():
        start = min(data["start"], key=date_compare_key)
        end = max(data["end"], key=date_compare_key)
        line = f"{user}  start  {start} and end {end}\n"
        out.write(line)
```

**f2.txt**

```
user A  start  10:30 and end 11:30
user B  start  10:30 and end 10:40
user C  start  10:50 and end 12:30
```

---

An even more efficient approach would be to keep the first implementation, and just update the `start` and `end` values with values as they come along, instead of taking the `max` and `min` after collecting all the values. This however will lead to a slightly more complicated code. This can be an exercise for you to figure out :-).

Comment: if data file have more number of same user records.                                                   user A start 10:30
user B start 10:30
user B end   10:40
user C start 10:50
user A end   11:30
user C end   12:30                                                                                                        user A start 10:30
user B start 10:30
user B end   10:40
user C start 10:50
user A end   11:30
user C end   12:30

Comment: @dineb Then the solution above would need to be modified. What does the output file look like for that data?

Comment: New data entry in the file like below.                                                                               user A  start  10:30 and end 11:30
user B  start  10:30 and end 10:40
user C  start  10:50 and end 12:30                                                                         user A  start  10:30 and end 11:30
user B  start  10:30 and end 10:40
user C  start  10:50 and end 12:30

Comment: @dineb I've updated the question with a way to do this.